# Glassfish fails to restart from web portail but works with asadmin command

Tags: java, linux, glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-4.1

With the systemctl command `systemctl restart glassfish`, GF restarts properly.

But when I try to restart via the Web portail `https://127.0.0.1:4848` **=> server => Restart**, it fails without any reason.
Glassfish stops but never restarts.

I'm using **Glassfish 3.1.2.2** on **Fedora 20** with **java 1.6.0_45 x86_64**.
(I've also tried with **GF 4.1** on **Centos 7** with **java 1.8.0_66 x86_64** with the same result)

Here is my `glassfish.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=GlassFish Server

[Service]
User=glassfish
ExecStart=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain
ExecStop=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin stop-domain
ExecReload=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin restart-domain
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the service status `systemctl status glassfish -l`:

```
glassfish.service - GlassFish Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/glassfish.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2016-07-27 11:17:22 CEST; 52s ago
  Process: 9366 ExecStop=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin stop-domain (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 877 ExecStart=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1420 (code=exited, status=10)

Jul 27 10:24:20 decoder asadmin[877]: Successfully started the domain : domain1
Jul 27 10:24:20 decoder asadmin[877]: domain  Location: /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
Jul 27 10:24:20 decoder asadmin[877]: Log File: /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log
Jul 27 10:24:20 decoder asadmin[877]: Admin Port: 4848
Jul 27 10:24:20 decoder asadmin[877]: Command start-domain executed successfully.
Jul 27 10:24:20 decoder systemd[1]: Started GlassFish Server.
Jul 27 11:17:22 decoder systemd[1]: glassfish.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=10/n/a
Jul 27 11:17:22 decoder asadmin[9366]: CLI306 Warning - The server located at /usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1 is not running.
Jul 27 11:17:22 decoder asadmin[9366]: Command stop-domain executed successfully.
Jul 27 11:17:22 decoder systemd[1]: Unit glassfish.service entered failed state.
```

Here is the GF server.log:

```
[#|2016-07-27T11:17:20.805+0200|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Server restart initiated|#]

[#|2016-07-27T11:17:20.810+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin|_ThreadID=23;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|There should be only 1 primordial module but 0 primordial modules were found.|#]

Jul 27, 2016 11:17:21 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: JVM invocation command line:
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:PermSize=64m
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-client
-javaagent:/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Djava.security.policy=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Zurich
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish
-Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/lib/ext:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre/lib/ext:/usr/share/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
Jul 27, 2016 11:17:22 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: Successfully launched in 3 msec.
```

I've no SELinux denials, here is the only trace:

```
type=SERVICE_STOP msg=audit(1467638602.044:1652): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg=' comm="glassfish" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
```

Setting selinux mode to permissive has no effect. I've absolutely no idea what's going wrong...

---

I've also tested GF 3.1.2.2 on Centos 6 and it works. Maybe it is related to systemctl (Fedora 20 and Centos 7 both uses systemctl by default)?

Comment: Maybe this is the root cause [http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux](http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux) of this problem

Comment: Glassfish is not listening on port 80/443 but 8080/8181 (by default at least which is my configuration)

Comment: Have the similar issue, posted here: https://serverfault.com/questions/851683/glassfish-on-centos-7-systemd-asadmin-restart-domain-doesnt-work-as-expec

Answer (score 0):

I had to leave the default admin port in 8080 and to add a "Port Forwarding" Firewall rule from 80 to 8080 and then the Glassfish restart works correctly.

From https://serverfault.com/a/112798/393296 and the FirewallD rule was (for Centos7)

- sudo firewall-cmd --zone="***dmz***" --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080 --permanent
- sudo firewall-cmd --reload

Note: Remember to change your zone to your active one (in this case my active zone is dmz -- [more info about FirewallD Centos7](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/introduction-to-firewalld-on-centos))

Comment: I'm using Apache to redirect incoming http request to Glassfish. Glassfish has the default configuration (listenning for 8080 and 8181) so this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

need to add to the section [Service] `Restart=on-failure`

Comment: Just tried, the behavior remains the same with or without. Thanks anyway